# How to parse 不快な音をたてないために、水の流れる音を出すもの?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-を

I am having trouble with the following sentence [from this article about toilets](https://newsinslowjapanese.com/2020/09/15/nisj-361-tokyos-newest-landmark-the-transparent-toilet/) translated as "a thing that makes the sound of running water to avoid making an unpleasant noise"

> 不快な音をたてない**ために**、水**の**流れる音**を**出すもの

I learned [about the use of ために](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23052/whats-the-difference-between-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81%e3%81%ab-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab-and-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%ab-meaning-in-order-to) and [its nuances](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74938/nuanced-meaning-of-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81) and how の connects two nouns VS を who connects noun and verb but it seems i'm not yet comfortable with it :)

So my questions are :

1. Is ために used as *because of* or as *in order to* ? I would suppose *in order to* but i thought it would work like *A ために B* to say *to do B in order to achieve A* whereas here ために comes after 不快な音.
2. How does 水**の**流れる音**を**出すもの work ? I understand we "first" use を to connect the verb 流れる and the noun 出すもの and "then" connect the noun/phrase and 水 using の. Am i right ?
3. What about 流れる音 ? Is this considered a verb (~ "make the sound of something flawing") or a noun (~ "the sound of something flawing") ?

Comment: Um, do you know [otohime](http://yabai.com/p/4177)?

Comment: Related (regarding 水の流れる音): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/9831

Comment: 水の流れる音 (=水が流れる音 = sound of water flowing) consists of a *gapless* relative clause explained in the final part of [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010) and the noun it modifies. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44274/5010), too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ために means in order to and your understanding is correct, A ために B means to do B to achieve A, as in "make a sound of running water to achieve the result of not making other unpleasant sounds".

水の流れる音 is a noun. The 音 is the most important thing here and is expanded subsequently by 流れる and 水の as in the sound of running water. I believe you could also say 水が流れる音 to the same effect.