# I have some questions about transitivity: 貯める and 貯まる

Tags: grammar, phrases, transitivity

1. I can usually hear people say 'お金を貯めるために、アルバイトをする’, but if I use the 自動詞 '貯まる' instead of the 他動詞 in the sentence, like 'お金が貯まるために、アルバイトをする', is it also acceptable?
2. You know I have a big problem with using Japanese 自動詞 and 他動詞 properly, I always get confused with the differences between them. For instance, '車がへいに突き当たる’, in this phrase, the subject 'the car' has a direct action on the wall. Why is the verb '突き当たる' a 自動詞 and not a 他動詞?

Comment: I assumed you meant to compare 貯まる with 貯める instead of 溜める so I edited that part.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see...

1. <s>Both are grammatically correct</s>This is wrong.See [Difference between ために and ように](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12450/difference-between-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB)
   but still

   > a. お金を貯めるために、アルバイトをする。
   >   　"Do a part time job to save money."
   >
   > b. お金が貯まるために、アルバイトをする。
   >   　"Do a part time job so that money will be saved up."

   (b) gives a feeling that you don't have control over saving money; i.e., you start part timing and hope money will pile up. This is not the case with (a).
2. It is "The car crashed into the wall." and not "The car crashed the wall."

   In English, *crash* is both transitive and intransitive:

   > "MS Windows crashed." (Intransitive)
   >   "Buggy software crashed Windows." (Transitive)

Comment: 1.b definitely sounds wrong. You have to say お金が貯まるように、アルバイトをする. Otherwise agreed.

Answer (score 1):

'お金を貯めるために、アルバイトをする’ is correct, but 'お金が貯まるために、アルバイトをする' is wrong. I don't know it's because of grammar or just because of convention.

You can say with intransitive verb "お金が貯まるようにアルバイトする。".

Difference between transitive and intransitive you may recognize with `lay` and `lie`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to express purposes, ''ために'' and ''ように'' you know, they are distinguished clearly.  
  
''ために'' is used when you can do it by your intention.

> 旅行に行くために、お金を貯める。  
>   お金を貯めるために、アルバイトをする。  
>   風邪を治すために、寝ている。  
>   みんなに見せるために、大きく書く。

*行く*, *貯める* , *治す*, and *見せる* are thought to be done by your will.  
  
Then, please look at examples below. ''ように'' is used when others or other things do it, or you can't control it.

> 旅行に行けるように、お金を貯める。  
>   お金が貯まるように、アルバイトをする。  
>   風邪が治るように、寝ている。
>   みんなに見えるように、大きく書く。

*行ける*, *貯まる*, *治る*, and *見える* are not thought to be done by your will, so ''ように'' is used.
  
Although now you may think that ''貯める'' is always followed by ''ために'' not by ''ように'', ''ように'' can also follow ''貯める''.

> 彼がお金を貯める**ように**、貯金箱を買ってあげた。

You can not control whether he saves money. So ''ように'' is used.  
If you have him save money, you can say as below.

> 彼にお金を貯めさせる**ために**、貯金箱を買ってあげた。  
>   彼にお金を貯めてもらう**ために**、貯金箱を買ってあげた。