# Difference between ように VS ために

Tags: grammar, nuances

I have the next sentence in the book:

> 締め切りに間に合う『？』必死でレポートを書き上げた。
>
> 1)ために 2)ように

The answer is ように. But from my point of view, there is absolutely no grammatical difference between the 2 of them in the current sentence, and ために could be used as well. Because you're expressing your aim -> 締め切りに間に合う.

I also went through this article https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/how-to-express-aims/ to read about the difference between them and didn't find anything that will "stop me" from using ために. In this sentence.

Why it's wrong to use ために here?

Answer (score 2):

According to web sources ([1](https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6761), [2](https://www.native-japanese-waseda-tokyo.com/yoni-tameni-difference1/)), the basic rule is

- 無意志動詞 + ように
- 意志動詞 + ために

間に合う is not a volitional action, so ように should be used.

---

Some examples partially taken from the links above.

- 大学へ行くためにたくさん勉強した In order to enter a college, I studied hard.
- 大学に行けるようにたくさん勉強した I studied hard so that I can enter a college.

Potential forms are 無意志動詞.

- 嫌なことを忘れるためにたくさん運動した In order to forget unpleasant thing, I exercised a lot.
- 忘れないように紙に書いた I wrote it down so that I won't forget.

Here it is a bit more subtle, but 忘れる is a volitional action and 忘れない is something you don't have control over (Admittedly, I'm not sure if I can forget what I want to forget)

---

Related Questions:

- [Difference between ために and ように](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12450/45489)
- [ために and ように difference](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56711/45489)