# Does this ように mean "as if" or "so that". 恥ずかしさを誤魔化すように

Tags: meaning

In context, his girlfriend did something embarrassing and he called her out on it.

恥ずかしさを**誤魔化すように**、俺をそっと抱きしめ、そして右頬にキスをしてくる

I ask this because I have seen other sentences where 誤魔化す is used with ために e.g.

可愛く見せるだけでなく、恥ずかしさを誤魔化すために写真の前で舌を出す人は意外と多いはずです

This clearly states that it was done in order to hide their embarrassment. From my understanding ように and ために are not interchangeable, so I'm wondering if 誤魔化す can somehow be used with both ように and ために, or if the ように used above is not the same meaning as "so that".

Comment: Do Tim's and ssb's answers to this question help?https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12450/difference-between-ために-and-ように

Comment: Yes and no. In general, most usages of ように and ために are easy enough to understand when it means "so that" or "in order to "。However when ように is used with a verb before it that is not in the potential / ない form then it is not as clear.

Comment: ssb says ように is the appropriate choice when the actor doesn't have complete control over the outcome. My **guess** as a non-native speaker is that the verb 誤魔化す is something of a borderline case, since dissembling is easier in some circumstances than in others & people's confidence in their ability to hide their feelings may vary. In your first example, we know the girlfriend's effort to hide her embarrassment failed – otherwise, her boyfriend couldn't have written the sentence. I **think** this makes ように the only choice, but I hope you'll get an authoritative answer. This is a great question!